# Call method is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

This below supposed to alert 'true', but, it is alerting 'No item'. Where i went i wrong on this code. Any clue?

```
Array.prototype.CheckColor = function (datain) {
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (this[i] === datain) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return "No item";
        }
    }
}

var newstr = "red blue green".split(" ");
var oyrsval = Array.prototype.CheckColor.call(newstr, "blue");
alert(oyrsval);
```

Comment: because this is returning "No item" if the first item is not equal to datain

Comment: Move the `return "No item";` outside the for (after)

Comment: because at the first time, when red doesn't matches to blue, it goes to else statement where 'No Item' is returned and it comes out of function.

Comment: why are you using a loop if there is already a `return` operation after the first element (occurs at both if and else). Maybe the else statement were meant to occur after the loop, if there is no `datain` match in the object.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why aren't you just saying `var oyrsval = newstr.CheckColor("blue');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We it's already explained that your problem is because you return from the loop too early. I will propose another solution, maybe simpler:

```
Array.prototype.CheckColor = function (datain) {
    return this.some(function(el) {
        return datain === el;
    }) || 'No item';
}
```

[`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method is useful in this case. Also since you are extending prototype there is no need to go hard way with `Array.prototype.CheckColor.call(newstr, "blue")` when you can directly use `newstr.CheckColor("blue")`.

Check the demo.

```js
Array.prototype.CheckColor = function (datain) {
    return this.some(function(el) {
        return datain === el;
    }) || 'No item';
}

var found = "red blue green".split(" ").CheckColor("blue");
var notfound = "red blues green".split(" ").CheckColor("blue");
alert(found);
alert(notfound);
```

Finally if testing if the item is within array is the only thing you need to do, you can use already available [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```
newstr.indexOf("blue") !== -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
Array.prototype.CheckColor = function(datain){
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len;i++ ){
        if (this[i] === datain){
            return true; // Return true if found
        }
    } 
    return "No item"; // else return
}
```

Or simplier using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
Array.prototype.CheckColor = function(datain){
    return this.indexOf(datain) > -1 ? true : "No item";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the result for the first comparison in your `for`

Change your code to:

```
for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len;i++) {
    if (this[i] === datain) {
        return true;
    }
}

return "No item";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
Array.prototype.CheckColor = function(datain){

    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len;i++ ){

        if (this[i] === datain) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // if here, nothing found
    return "No item";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with looping over the array, but you could also regexp directly on the string:

```
String.prototype.CheckColor = function(datain) {
    return RegExp("\\b" + datain + "\\b").test(this);
}
```

In the real world I suppose you'd want to escape special regexp characters inside `datain`.

Comment: why rewrite the indexOf method ?

Comment: Because we only want separate words, that's what the `\b` is about.